# "Dismiss All Completed Tasks"

Tags: magento2, bulk-actions

I'm doing automatic product imports and get lots of system messages in top of admin area. It's generally a good thing, because messages with errors are displayed first, but how to clear all these messages at once?

Is there any other way to do that without interacting with database (magento_acknowledged_bulk table)? Clicking on "Dismiss All Completed Tasks" only removes 5 messages at a time.